# If a column is used in a HAVING comparison, does MySQL use the first value in that column?

Tags: mysql, sql, standards

I already know the following is poor SQL code, but writing it has brought up a question concerning how MySQL deals with columns in comparisons.

The task is to determine the brand for which the maximum number of products has sold between two given dates.  The following code produces the correct answer (note use of ORDER BY in the inner query):

```
Select SUB.Brand_id, SUB.Brand_name, SUB.Brand_Type, SUB.Total <p>
FROM
(
    Select Brand_id, Brand_name, Brand_Type, SUM(line_qty) AS Total
    FROM LGLINE 
    NATURAL JOIN LGINVOICE 
    NATURAL JOIN LGPRODUCT 
    NATURAL JOIN LGBRAND
    Where INV_Date Between '2011-11-01' AND '2011-12-05'
    Group by Brand_name
    Order by Total DESC   -- Note the order by in the subquery
) as SUB
HAVING (MAX(SUB.TOTAL) = SUB.Total);
```

This produces a single record, which is the correct answer:

'30', 'LONG HAUL', 'CONTRACTOR', '590'

By contrast, the following code (absent the subquery ORDER BY) produces no results:

```
Select SUB.Brand_id, SUB.Brand_name, SUB.Brand_Type, SUB.Total <p>
FROM
(
    Select Brand_id, Brand_name, Brand_Type, SUM(line_qty) AS Total
    FROM LGLINE 
    NATURAL JOIN LGINVOICE 
    NATURAL JOIN LGPRODUCT 
    NATURAL JOIN LGBRAND
    Where INV_Date Between '2011-11-01' AND '2011-12-05'
    Group by Brand_name
    -- Order by Total DESC.    NOTE: I have commented out this line
) as SUB
HAVING (MAX(SUB.TOTAL) = SUB.Total);
```

I suspect that MySQL is interpreting the `SUB.Total` **after** the equals sign as the **first** value in the `SUB.Total` column.  Two part question:

1) Can I use MySQL in any way to confirm my suspicion?  Is there any way to use EXPLAIN or any other statement to help?

2) If my suspicion is correct, this seems quite an arbitrary design decision.  I would hope for an error instead.  Is there any SQL documentation that states this is correct (or incorrect) behavior?

Note, this is largely an academic question, since I could rewrite the query and be done with it.  However, I'm interested in what this says about the workings of MySQL.

Comment: I think you could test this for yourself faster than asking the question

Comment: You cannot delete content like that. People have answered it. Destroying your question invalidates their answer. If you don't want it online, you shouldn't have asked the question. By posting it here you have irrevocably and perpetually licensed the content to the site. Please leave it in place.

Comment: Your `having` as shown doesn't make sense because it is applied to a query that does not use a `group by` - and it is essentially illegal SQL, only MySQL chooses to return random data rather than throwing an error: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM ints HAVING i > 7;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 1 FROM ints HAVING i > 7;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'i' in 'having clause'
mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have stumbled onto mysql's non-standard grouping support.

Unlike every other database (AFAIK), mysql allows you to not list every non-aggregate column in the group by clause. Where other databases will throw a syntax exception, mysql instead returns *one* row for every unique combination of columns that .*are* listed in the group by clause.

According to the documentation, the row returned for each group is chosen at random, however as a matter of practicality, it is always the *first* row encountered. That is, if you order the rows using an inner query *before* applying the group by, you'll get the first row from the ordered rows. Thus happens 100% of he time, without any exceptions.

I personally am completely comfortable relying in this behaviour, but others are more anal and refuse to use this highly convenient behaviour.

Had you listed all non-aggregate columns, like this:

```
GROUP BY Brand_id, Brand_name, Brand_Type
```

you would have the correct results you expected.

Comment: well, so far anyway - but then I'm in the other camp ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry I look at it like this: the only way this behaviour will change is if you do an upgrade to mysql, and that would be tested on a test server and all regression testing done before upgrading everywhere else, so any change will be detected and queries reworked before affecting any systems. But why do the extra work of doing the queries "properly" if there's no evidence it will ever be needed? More likely, a) it will never happen and b) the specification will be changed to officially declare that the first row encountered is returned